# Setting up endpoints (Camel)

Tags: apache-camel

I am new to Camel and learning to setup routes.

So I started with a simple scenario, a URL that I hit and it returns me some data. For this example I have used http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all for returning that data.

This is the setup for my path

```
from("direct:greet")
      .autoStartup(true)
      .routeId("greet")
      .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(HttpMethods.GET))
      .to("http4://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all")
```

Now I have requestMapping to a URL `/check` and when I hit this URL `http://localhost:8080/check` it returns this

> {
>       "timestamp": 1527882311362,
>       "status": 404,
>       "error": "Not Found",
>       "message": "No message available",
>       "path": "/check"
>   }

I was expecting the JSON response to show up with the data for all the countries listed which you see when you hit the URL(http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all) in your browser.

The mapping is in other class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/check", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String get(@RequestParam(value = "name") String name) {
    return serviceProcessor.getServiceResponse(name);
```

getServiceResponse goes as follows:

```
public String getServiceResponse(String name) {
final ModelCamelContext context = userServiceRoute.getContext();
final ProducerTemplate template = new DefaultProducerTemplate(context);
try {
  template.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
  LOGGER.error("Error starting producerTemplate with userServiceRoute" + e);
}
final Endpoint endpoint = context.getEndpoint("direct:greet");
template.setDefaultEndpoint(endpoint);
return template.requestBody((Object)name, String.class);
```

}

Is there something wrong with the path setup or the approach itself is wrong here?

Comment: where is your /check mapping? and how are you calling it?

Comment: @pvpkiran I have added the mapping in the description